# Is there a way to use RedirectToAction or something equivalent in a ASP.Net Forms page?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, webforms

I have a mixed environment with both Forms and MVC v2 pages.  I want to redirect to a MVC page from a Forms page.

Usually I use RedirectToAction when within the controller.  But when I am in a Asp.Net Forms type page I can't really use that.

I'm digging around the framework to find a solution, thought I would ask here in case someone already knows the answer to this.

Comment: Did you try

    Response.Redirect("MVC_Page_Url")

Comment: Yes that works, but I would like to just be able to say the controller name and action name, and for it to generate me the URL based on the MVC routes already configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on my own.  Here is how I solved this:

```
var controllerName = "NameOfMyController";
var actionName = "NameOfMyAction";

//Lets resolve the URL for the controller/action based on the existing routes
var routes = RouteTable.Routes;
var virtualPathData = routes.GetVirtualPath(
                        null,
                        new RouteValueDictionary {
                                {"Controller", controllerName}, 
                                {"Action", actionName}
                        });

/* resolvedUrl should now contain the full URL to 
the controller/action defined at the beginging */
var resolvedUrl =  virtualPathData == null ? "" : virtualPathData.VirtualPath;
```